Сломанный вывод requests в python
Всем здоровья, комрады! На досуге следующий кейс:
Имеется Linux Mint 24
Python 3.12.3
Пишу код для взаимодействия с API. Использую всего две либы в проекте (скачанные) : requests и bs4. Создаю venv чтобы не захламлять глобальное окружение. Requests выдает сломанный response (код 200). Запрос проходит, получаю ответ (ответ в JSON) в консоль пишет всякую кадабру. Скрин приложу. Если прогоняю через глобальный интерпретатор то все ок. Очевидно что чего то не хватает, но я не могу нащупать где. Скорее всего, где то сломалась либа. Подскажите как добиться адекватного ответа на запрос.
Код:
import requests
import json
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime 

base_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
func_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'functions')
sys.path.append(func_dir)

import api

AVAILABLE_TAPS = 6000

def tap (count : int, AVAILABLE_TAPS) :
    time_stamp = round(time.time())
    payload = {"count":count,
               "availableTaps":AVAILABLE_TAPS,
               "timestamp":time_stamp}
    opt_res = requests.options(url=api.tap, headers=api.tap_opt_headers)
    print('[OPTIONS] Code : ', opt_res.status_code)
    post_res = requests.post(url=api.tap, headers=api.tap_post_headers, json=payload)
    print('[TAP] Code : ', post_res.status_code)

    return json.loads(post_res.text)

def sync () :
    opt_res = requests.get(url=api.sync, headers=api.opt_sync_headers)
    print('[OPTIONS] Code : ', opt_res.status_code)
    post_res = requests.post(url=api.sync, headers = api.post_sync_headers)
    print('[SYNC] Code :', post_res.status_code)
    data = json.loads(post_res.text)
    #last_sync = data['clickerUser']["lastSyncUpdate"]
    #print("[SYNC] Last Sync : ", datetime.fromtimestamp(last_sync))


    return data['clickerUser']


def main() :
    data = sync()
    coins = round(data['balanceCoins'])
    last_sync = data["lastSyncUpdate"]
    level = data['level']
    av_taps = data['availableTaps']
    print(av_taps)
    #AVAILABLE_TAPS = av_taps
    earnPerTap = data['earnPerTap']
    tapsRecover = data['tapsRecoverPerSec']
    maxTaps = data['maxTaps']
    #print(AVAILABLE_TAPS)
    print(coins)
    #tap(1, AVAILABLE_TAPS)
    time.sleep(3600)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Вывод при запуске из venv (https://imgur.com/a/0dIIN6U)
Вывод при запуске из глобального окружения юзера:
[OPTIONS] Code :  404
[SYNC] Code : 200
6500
110056206


Покажите содержимое headers - я почти уверен, что объяснение находится именно в них

Заголовки одни и те же. Вы настаиваете?

Настаиваю . . .

headers = {  'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 6.0.1; HTC One M8 Pro Build/MRA58K) AppleWebKit/534.45 (KHTML, like Gecko)  Chrome/49.0.3424.301 Mobile Safari/603.5',  'Accept':'*/*',  'Accept-Language':'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',  'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br, zstd',     'Authorization':'**********',  'Origin':'*********',  'Connection':'keep-alive',  'Sec-Fetch-Dest':'empty',  'Sec-Fetch-Mode':'cors',  'Sec-Fetch-Site':'same-site',  'Priority':'u=4',     'Content-Length':'0',  'TE':'trailers' }

'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br, zstd' - ну вот, вы сами запросили сжатие ответа, а библиотеки для разжатия в venv видимо не установили (ну а в глобале они видимо установлены)

Абстракция понятна, реализация не очень))
Конкретнее, какие либы нужны? И как их использовать? Впервые сталкиваюсь с таким кейсом

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/community/faq/#encoded-data

Решение:
pip install brotli в venv


Но если сервер однажды решит начать присылать zstd, то всё опять сломается
